# Wait Until another function finish

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem. Two function are called from one event almost on the same time. Function1 is doing some asynchronous staff  :

```
function1 (callback_Data){  
   //some other callbacks here  
}

function2 (){

}
```

I want function2 to wait until all callbacks which are in function1 to finish and then to start.

Comment: Look into Promises: https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: Couldn't you just make function1 call function2 after it's completed?  For example, if function1 is looping 10 times in a for loop, just place a function2() call after the for loop.

Comment: You should use `Promise` and `all()` method to synchronise your function2 call.

Comment: Depends on what `function1()` does. Show more detail as per [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Promise States

A promise can be in one of 3 states:

**Pending**  the promise’s outcome hasn’t yet been determined, because the asynchronous operation that will produce its result hasn’t completed yet.
**Fulfilled** - the asynchronous operation has completed, and the promise has a value.
**Rejected** - the asynchronous operation failed, and the promise will never be fulfilled. In the rejected state, a promise has a reason that indicates why the operation failed.

```
var greetingPromise = sayHello();
greetingPromise.then(function (greeting) {
   console.log(greeting);    // 'hello world’
 });
```

This block can help you to execute the first function 1 then after it will goes to function 2.

Comment: Assumes that `function1()` returns a promise...otherwise using `$.when` is pointless

Comment: offcource it should be

Comment: What do you mean *"of course"*?. No mention of that in your answer and you have no idea what it currently returns

Comment: @charlietfl I know only these if i am wrong then please edit this answer for better answer

Comment: Yes, promises is a powerful mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Call function2() at the very end of function1. Please be careful if there are any asyncronous callbacks. In this case call function2 at the end of the last callback.

```
function1 (callback_Data) {
  // some logic here

  // async function
  asyncFunction(param1, param2, function() {
    // the logic that is executed, when asyncFunction is completed
    function2();
  });
}

function2() {
  // some other logic
}
```

Comment: what if some code is executing asynchronously inside function1 but before function2 call?

Comment: I added a asyncFunction with anonymous callback function.

Comment: hmm, what if multiple async executions will be there?

Answer (score 0):

If something is executed asynchronously in `function1` then furnction 2 will not be blocked until they finished, becaused they are scheduled to be execute.

You can initiate a promise, and pass function2 in `then` and when all executions are finished from `function1` you can resolved that promise.

Comment: yes, it looks, strange. but I agree with you about the promises

Comment: @qiAlex what looks strange?

Answer (score -1):

It is a simple method you can call the second function after the 1st function complete execution.
 like this

```
function1 (callback_Data){ 
//some other callbacks here 
function2 ();//here is the function call
}
function2 (){
//your code
}
```

Comment: what if some code is executing asynchronously inside function1 but before function2 call?

Comment: Its not that simple, an even must only fire those two function.. I have to use commands like promises or deferred .. But dont know how .Thanks!

Comment: then you can use `setTimeOut()`  to handle this .

Answer (score -1):

You can use promises for async actions

```
'use strict';

// creating object promise
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  setTimeout(() => {
    // this will make promise fulfilled with result "result"
    resolve("result");
    // this will make promise rejected with result "error"
    // reject("error");
  }, 1000);

});

// promise.then adds functions on success and failure
promise
  .then(
    result => {
      // first function - will be executed on resolve
      alert("Fulfilled: " + result); // result - argument resolve
    },
    error => {
      // second function will be executed on reject
      alert("Rejected: " + error); // error - argument reject
    }
  );
```